# Auto refresh Google Apps Scripts webapp UI?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, google-apps-script

I have created a simple webapp using Google Apps Scripts.  The UI simply displays a couple of numbers being continuous updated in a FusionTable.  A custom data acquisition system is running locally in my house and sending new results every minute up to the FusionTable.  I wish to update the UI on my GAS webapp at one-minute intervals so that the new numbers are displayed.

I have half of the problem solved by running a time-driver trigger to periodically grab data from the FusionTable and store the numbers in my script's own ScriptDb.  So this works fine to get my data in the right neighborhood.  But I still do not see how to periodically update a textbox in my UI with the new data.

So far I have manually configured a refresh button on the UI that user can click to update the display with the most recent numbers stored in the ScriptDb.  I am so close I can taste it!

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `UiInstance.addTimer` method for auto refresh, but it's not documented and maybe not supported.

Its syntax is `UiInstance.addTimer( ServerHandler , interval);`

See the sample code below.

```
function doGet(e) {

  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  

  app.add(app.createLabel(new Date()).setId("label"));

  

  app.addTimer(app.createServerHandler("update") , 1000);

  

  return app;

}



function update(e){

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  app.getElementById("label").setText(new Date());

  app.addTimer(app.createServerHandler("update") , 1000);


  return app;

}
```

A sample app can be found [here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwdWnOawaCKZk85ZIBpm5DPupcdby3kn-PeOkqj5dxBUXUhmTQ/exec).

Comment: Nice.  Thanks for the tip.   I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Okay, this was very easy to implement.  I was confused at first by your use of addTimer() in the two function doGet() and update().  It looks like the timer event created here is a one-time shot, hence the need to call it inside the update() function.  This ensures a continued sequence of events.  In my implementation I did not call addTimer() from doGet().  Instead I simply call update() from doGet(), and that is enough to get the ball rolling.  Thanks very much for the idea.

Comment: Using a timer causes an 'unexpected eroor' if the creation op the app is in global scope. Without a timer that's not a problem at all and useful

Answer (score 2):

Use a spreadsheet for display. They autoupdate.

Stackoverflow, this is not a thanks but the solution, but for you:

1. Make a spreadsheet
2. add a service for posting
3. have service update spreadsheet
4. watch spreadsheet

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Google Apps Script doesn't yet have a timer facility to update the UI at frequent intervals. However, there is a hack that I wrote a while back and is available in the old Apps Script forum at 
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps-script/2pqhh_eTIvQ

There have been refinements over that you can search for in stackoverflow, but the basic premise remains the same i.e. you exploit the fact that you can programatically change the value of a checkbox AND trigger its change handler.