# Google Spreadsheet Script onChange event not firing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, onchange

I am trying to fire an onChange event and it is not working.

I have the following simple code:

```
function onChange(){
  Logger.log("onChange event fired");
}

function onEdit(){
  Logger.log("onEdit event fired");
}
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events

According the this document, the onChange event should be fired when a row is inserted. It does not get fired. The onEdit function gets fired when you manipulate a cell, but I need an event to be fired when the user inserts a row as well.

Any thoughts?

Comment: that's an example of how a function works, if you want the onchange event for a particular cell, you should consult the api.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers
Show me where you've got onChange trigger?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358808/google-apps-script-run-when-spreadsheet-is-change-by-another-script) so.

Answer (score 11):

Try to use signatures with one parameter:

```
function onChange(e){
  Logger.log("onChange event fired");
}

function onEdit(e){
  Logger.log("onEdit event fired");
}
```

And then register those functions in ScriptEditor:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

onChange is an install-able trigger. Use the following function to install the trigger.

```
    function createSpreadsheetChangeTrigger() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('onChange')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onChange()
      .create();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In the script editor I clicked the Resources menu and selected 'All your triggers' from there I was able to register my onChange function to actually be triggered on change of the spreadsheet.

Edit: People were telling me to do this with code, I couldn't get that to work. Found the gui method buried in the docs.

Comment: Why do you need onChange event to fire? What can you get from the event ojbect? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67931041/google-sheet-how-to-get-the-actual-change-when-onchange-event-fires/67931286#67931286