# Fire onChange trigger from google script event

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that create a sheet when an user from my company is pressing a button. When he does so, I need to protect the sheet for certains ranges.

As you may know, an user cannot protect and delete himself afterwards, so it doesn't work in my case.

So I thought about creating an onChange trigger which fire when a sheet is created from the button.

Unfortunately, onChange doesn't seems to fire when the spreadsheet's content or structure is changed by Google Script.

Is there a way to do so ? Or can I protect my sheets from another way ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41586926/1595451 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/17358808/1595451

Comment: More related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26639180/1595451