# addTimer not working with global app in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

I read about the (undocumented) addTmer and would like to use it for updating the UI.

The example at [Auto refresh Google Apps Scripts webapp UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638721/auto-refresh-google-apps-scripts-webapp-ui) does work well

```
// This code works
function doGet(e)
{
 var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Test addTimer - createApplication in doget');
 var appLocal = app;

  var handler = appLocal.createServerHandler("update");
  appLocal.addTimer(handler , 4000);

  var label = appLocal.createLabel(new Date()).setId("label"); 
  appLocal.add(label);

  return appLocal;
}

function update(e)
{
  var appLocal = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
//  var appLocal = app;
  appLocal.getElementById("label").setText(new Date());
  var handler = appLocal.createServerHandler("update");
  appLocal.addTimer(handler , 1000);

  return appLocal;
}
```

but if I move createApplication out of doGet() into a global variable, an 'unexpected error' will occur at runtime.
Without addTimer it IS possible to move createApplication out of doget() into global scope.

```
// This code will crash at runtime
 var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Test addTimer , createApplication outside doGet');

function doGet(e)
{ 
  var appLocal = app;

  var handler = appLocal.createServerHandler("update");
  appLocal.addTimer(handler , 4000);

  var label = appLocal.createLabel(new Date()).setId("label"); 
  appLocal.add(label);

  return appLocal;
}

function update(e)
{
  var appLocal = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
//  var appLocal = app;
  appLocal.getElementById("label").setText(new Date());
  var handler = appLocal.createServerHandler("update");
  appLocal.addTimer(handler , 1000);

  return appLocal;
}
```

As I've seen global use of

`var app = createApplication();`

and i suppose more people would like to use addTimer as well, I post my experience here.

Maybe someone can explain WHY this is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call a service outside of any function, this call is executed each time any function is called, that's to say when `doGet` is called but also when the handler function is called and also when the timer triggers a script execution.

It means that you are calling `UiApp.createApplication()` 2 (and more) times... this is not a good idea and generates an 'unexpected error'.

by the way, what would be the advantage of that approach ?

Uiapp is designed to work with a main service call and handlers, each handler getting the active instance using `getActiveApplication()` why are you trying to use it differently?

Comment: Will UiApp.createApplication() really be called X times if you define a global variable  var app = UiApp.createApplication();   That would be VERY ineffecicient indeed. The advantage of using a global variable would be you can use 'app' in every function without adding var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication(); in every function.  I changed it already =, and it works.

Comment: Yes indeed, it will run multiple time. You can verify that easily using a spreadsheet and changing a cell color in a "global" call and look at the sheet when any function is called.