# Getting Cannot call method "getRange" of null error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
var METADATA_SHEET_NAME = 'MetaData';

function readMetaData() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(METADATA_SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 2);
  var fixVersion = range.getValue();
  Logger.log(fixVersion);
  return fixVersion;  
}
```

In my current google script, I already have Sheet with Name `MetaData`. I am storing a sheet name in variable `METADATA_SHEET_NAME`. if I pass sheet name directly in `getSheetByName()` method, it works perfectly but when I am passing variable name(in which I have stored sheet name) it is giving

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null.

Comment: Indicates a problem with a sheet named MetaData. Do you have a sheet named MetaData with the same capitalization?

Comment: @ScampMichael yes I have a sheet named with MetaData only

Comment: Try placing Logger.log(METADATA_SHEET_NAME); in your function and seeing what it returns.

Answer (score 1):

Check for typos as it's working for me. It's okay to assign the sheet name to a variable.

Here I have a sheet named 'Sheet1' which I assigned to `METADATA_SHEET_NAME` variable. Now I'm going to fetch value from row 1 col 2 as per your code.

```
[17-07-06 05:17:16:829 PDT] Response1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Global variables in Google apps script aren't persistent. [see top answer here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721226/how-to-define-global-variable-in-google-apps-script)

Check out [this blog post](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2012/05/insider-tips-for-using-apps-script-and.html) for loading global variables if you really need to