# Calling variables from another function

Tags: google-apps-script

Trying to call a variable from a sub function, but "sheet" is not defined. Any suggestions on how to call it?

```
function getDate(){
var mnthYearDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date,"EST","MMM yyyy");
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(mnthYearDate);
}

function getValue(){
getDate();
var target = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
}
```

Comment: This post might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721226/how-to-define-global-variable-in-google-apps-script

Answer (score 1):

Return it from your getValue() function and pass it as parameter to getValue(sheet) function.

Answer (score 1):

The variable '`sheet`' here is only known in your function `getDate` because you defined it there. To make it available to other functions, define it outside like what I did here.

```
var sheet;

function getDate(){
var mnthYearDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date,"EST","MMM yyyy");
 sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(12345);
}

function getValue(){
    getDate();
    var target = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
    Logger.log(target);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//---GLOBAL VARIABLES---
var mnthYearDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date,"EST","MMM yyyy");
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(mnthYearDate);
var target;

//---RETRIEVE DATA---
function getValue(){
 target = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
}

//---GET DATA FROM OTHER FUNCTION---
function showInLog() {
gatValue();
Logger.log("Show target: "+target)
}
```