# Creating a Google Workspace add on using Apps Script — variable isn't being properly referenced across functions

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm writing an Google Workspace add-on for Google Calendar, using Google Apps Script.

I'm having trouble getting different functions to reference the value of a variable

1. I have a startDate variable defined at the root set to "today"
2. In createDate it gets set to "tomorrow"
3. It then displays it correctly in a card header as "Default start tomorrow"
4. When you click on the button, reviseStartDate is called
5. A new card is created, and it's header incorrectly says "Revised start today" instead of "Revised start tomorrow"

Here is my code, you can run it as-is:

```
var startdate = "today"; // Define startdate as a global variable with an initial value

function onOpen() {
 var card = createCard();
  return card;
}

function createCard() {
  startdate = "tomororw"; // Update the value of startdate
  var button = CardService.newTextButton()
    .setText('Revise start date')
    .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction()
    .setFunctionName('reviseStartDate'));

  var section = CardService.newCardSection()
    .addWidget(button);

  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
    .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle('Default start:' + startdate))
    .addSection(section)

  return card.build();
}

function reviseStartDate() {
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
    .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle("Revised start:" +startdate));

  return card.build();
}
```

And here is part of my manifest

```
  "calendar": {
  "homepageTrigger": {
    "runFunction": "onOpen"
  },
  "eventOpenTrigger": {
    "runFunction": "showFreeTime"
  }
```

How can I allow start date to be read and written by multiple functions, in "regular" javascript this would work fine. Thanks

[Google add-ons docmentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/building-workspace-addons)

[Google Apps Script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Apps Script handles these variables differently, they are evaluated in every execution and calling the script to create a card is considered a separate execution:

1. Script runs to create a card, this card is now displayed in the side bar but that doesn't mean that the script is still executing, GAS already completed the requested operation which was creating a card.
2. Using the UI in the already created card runs the `reviseStartDate()` function but that is considered a new and separate execution (as shown in the execution log) meaning that the variables are re-evaluated.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24721226/19602805) that explained a similar behavior and found a workaround that involved using the `CacheService` to store your variables, this modification would yield the desired output:

```
var cache = CacheService.getUserCache();


function onHomepage() {
  var card = createCard();
  return card;
}

function createCard() {

  cache.put("startdate","tomorrow");
  var startdate = cache.get("startdate");

  var button = CardService.newTextButton()
    .setText('Revise start date')
    .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction()
      .setFunctionName('reviseStartDate'));

  var section = CardService.newCardSection()
    .addWidget(button);

  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
    .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle('Default start: ' + startdate))
    .addSection(section)

  return card.build();
}

function reviseStartDate() {

  var startdate = cache.get("startdate");

  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
    .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle("Revised start: " + startdate));

  return card.build();
}
```

Another alternative would be to use [User Properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties) that work in a similar fashion.

---

#### Some Docs:

- Google Apps Script - [Cache Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache-service)

Comment: That's gold, it works — thank you so much Bryan