# How to reassign Gloabl Variable In Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, global-variables, add-on

I'm using **Google App Script**. I want to **reassign** my **Global variable** named **myname**. I had **reassigned** the value of **myname** to **Testing Name**. It **assigns** the value to **myname** on click of **Set Name** **Button** as I console in the **handleSetName** function. But when I got the value of **myname** on the **handleGetName** function it's getting **undefined**. I had pasted the **code** below and attached the logger image so that you can see output.

How can I **reassign** global variables?

Can anyone **guide** me on this?

**Code.gs**

```
var myname = "";

function loadMTS(event) {
    const button1 = CardService.newTextButton().setText("Set Name")
        .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.FILLED)
        .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName("handleSetName"));

    const button2 = CardService.newTextButton().setText("Get Name")
        .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.FILLED)
        .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName("handleGetName"));

    return card.addSection(CardService.newCardSection().addWidget(button1).addWidget(button2)).build();
}

function handleSetName(e) {
    myname = "Testing Name";
    console.log("Name after change in handleSetName Fucntion :", myname);
}

function handleGetName(e) {
    console.log("Name : ", myname);
}
```

[image: Ouput Image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a Google Workspace add on using Apps Script — variable isn't being properly referenced across functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76303061/creating-a-google-workspace-add-on-using-apps-script-variable-isnt-being-prop)

Comment: That will work fine. But maybe it saved the variable for all time in-app script.